# Unable to access media library, but getting an error as forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. I have administrative rights

Tags: media

Unable to access media library, but getting an error as forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. I have administrative rights

Comment: Could you provide a screen capture of the error with the url (you can blur out the domain)? That would be helpful.

Comment: you can try to check the write permissions and the users who own the folder